# Can OS X's password assistant be used in 3rd party apps?

Tags: macos, cocoa, passwords

I'd like to use OS X's password assistant in my 3rd party app.

[image]

I couldn't find anything in Apple's docs, but [this old post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/153192-how-do-access-the-password-assistant-dialog.html) says that password assistant is accessed through a private API. Is this still true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely true but there are plenty of examples online for creating "secure password generators" - many of which are liberally licensed so you can use the approach (if not the exact code) to make your own.

Like recipe book and address book apps, there are many "password generator" apps out there for the Mac already, primarily because it's an easy target for a beginning developer to create.

If it were me, I'd just add a new window controller and xib then implement my own in a style that looks like it's part of my app. The UI is dead simple and so is the "generator" routine.